# Enumerate over string instead of iterating with range() and len()

Tags: python, python-3.x, enumerate

I wrote a function, that returns a new string made of every second character starting with the first.

So that for example "Pizza" yields "Pza", "Maogtbhdewr" yields "Mother".

This code is with `range()` and `len()`:

```py
def string_skip(string):
    new_string = ""
    for n in range(0, len(string)):
        if n % 2 == 0:
            new_string += string[n]

    return new_string
```

The code above works as expected. But `pylint` shows an info suggesting to use `enumerate()` instead of iterating with `range()` and `len()`. So, I tried to rewrite my code without the two built-ins, and I've also read through the documentaion. But I still could not get it to work.

My question: How do I use `enumerate()` instead of using `range()` and `len()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes you can, strings are iterables too.

```
def string_skip(string):
    new_string = ""
    for i, n in enumerate(string):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            new_string += n

    return new_string
```

Answer (score 3):

```
s="Pizza"
s[::2]
Out[3]: 'Pza'
```

You don't even need range and len or even enumerate

Comment: that's right, but I asked for a solution with `enumerate()`

Comment: I understand. Still, I think the example in the original question does not fit. In this case, using enumerate adds an unjustified overhead. In other words enumerate should be used when actually needed

Answer (score 2):

Try this function:

```
def string_skip(st):
    return ''.join([j for i, j in enumerate(x) if not i % 2])
```

---

`for i, j in enumerate(string)` simply unpacks the following:

```
0, string[0]
1, string[1]
2, string[2]
...
```

---

```
>>> for i, j in enumerate('Pizza'):
...     print i, j
... 
0 P
1 i
2 z
3 z
4 a
>>>
```

Comment: If you are going to bind the function to a name, use the `def` statement. `lambda` is for functions that don't need a name in the current scope (for example, when you are creating the function simply to pass as an argument to another function).

Comment: I'd echo chpner. Using `join` is a good idea, but packing it all into a one-liner just makes it harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @attersson, you can rely on the [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-slice) capability of Python sequences (anything which can be indexed):

```
>>> s = "Pizza"
>>> s[::2]
'Pza'
```

Instead of only indexing one character (`s[2]`), or a range of characters (`s[2:4]`), you can specify the *step* to use when iterating with the third value between the square brackets.

In summary, indexing in Python works as `[start:stop:step]` where start is inclusive, and stop is exclusive. By default `start=0`, `stop=len(...)`, and `step=1`:

```
>>> s[2]
'z'
>>> s[2:4]
'zz'
>>> s[1::2]
'iz'
```

---

Now if you really want to use enumerate, you can rely on the index as it is yielded:

```
>>> for i, letter in enumerate(s):
>>>     if i % 2 == 0:
>>>         print(letter)
```

Comment: And it is also more Pythonic and efficient.

Comment: I would say it is also more readable -- which is what one likes about Python.

Comment: I agree with all that. This is just for practice and better understanding purposes.

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```py
def str_func(mystr):

    newstr = ''

    for i, char in enumerate(mystr):
        if not i%2:
            newstr+=char
    return newstr
```

If you're feeling particularly fancy, you could use a list comprehension and `join`:

```py
def str_func(mystr):
    return "".join([char for i,char in enumerate(mystr) if not i%2 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out:

```
def string_skip_2(string):
   string = list(string)
   new_string = ''
   for i in range(len(string)):
       if int(list(enumerate(string))[i][0]) % 2 == 0:
           new_string += list(enumerate(string))[i][1]
   return new_string
```

Comment: I wanted to use `enumerate()` __instead__ of `range()` and `len()`.

Answer (score 0):

To provide yet another option, which iterates over the elements similarly to enumerate, yet a bit more elegantly:

```
def string_skip(string):
    new_string = ""
    iterator = iter(string)
    for letter in iterator:
        new_string += letter
        next(iterator)
    return new_string
```